Laravel Attempt to read property "lang" on null
I am trying to run laravel project on my server & it is throwing some error. Same project working fine on other server. Please help me to solve problem. Herewith I am attaching screen shot.
Attempt to read property "lang" on null
Illuminate \ Foundation \ Bootstrap\ HandleExceptions: 3handleError


Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include your relevant code and the error as text in the question rather than as an image. See [mcve] for more details.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It looks like Laravel cannot find the user with ID 1 because that user probably doesn't exist. Ensure the user exists on your server. You should probably also safeguard this by checking if the user is not null i.e:
$user=\App\Models\User::find(1);
if($user) {
    \App::setLocale($user->lang);
}

